# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (Guard decorator)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I've a AuthGuard who check the JWT token in controllers. I want use this Guard in controllers to check authentication. I've this error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?, +). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the current context.

## TestController.ts

```
import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  Body,
  HttpCode,
  HttpStatus,
  UseInterceptors,
  UseGuards,
} from "@nestjs/common";
import { TestService } from "Services/TestService";
import { CreateTestDto } from "Dtos/CreateTestDto";
import { ApiConsumes, ApiProduces } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { AuthGuard } from "Guards/AuthGuard";

@Controller("/tests")
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
export class TestController {
  constructor(
    private readonly testService: TestService,
  ) {}

  @Post("/create")
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  @ApiConsumes("application/json")
  @ApiProduces("application/json")
  async create(@Body() createTestDto: CreateTestDto): Promise<void> {
    // this.testService.blabla();
  }
}
```

## AuthGuard.ts

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthService } from "Services/AuthService";
import { UserService } from "Services/UserService";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private readonly authService: AuthService,
        private readonly userService: UserService,
    ) {}

    async canActivate(dataOrRequest, context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
        try {
            // code is here
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your module?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`AuthService` (the dependency that could not be resolved) must be available in the scope containing the controller which uses the guard.

**What does it mean?**

Include `AuthService` in the `providers` of the module loading your controller.

e.g.

```
@Module({
  controllers: [TestController],
  providers: [AuthService, TestService, UserService],
})
export class YourModule {}
```

**EDIT** - Forgot to mention that an other clean way (maybe cleaner, depending on the context) consists in **importing the module** that offers (`exports`) the service.

e.g.

```
@Module({
  providers: [AuthService],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule],
  controllers: [TestController],
  providers: [TestService, UserService],
})
export class YourModule {}
```

Comment: Importing the service directly causes a whole new instance to be created every single time, so you can end up with multiple instances throughout your app. Importing the module ensures that doesn't happen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383271/nestjs-import-service-or-the-whole-module