# Nestjs import service or the whole module

Tags: nestjs

I'm new in Nestjs, and I don't understand when I need to import the whole module or only the service if I want to Inject in another module.

For example:
I have my loggingModule

```js
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { LoggingService } from "./logging.service";

@Module({
    providers: [LoggingService],
    exports: [LoggingService],
})
export class LoggingModule {}
```

with my logginService:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

@Injectable()
export class LoggingService {

    logToConsole(logString: string) {
        console.log(logString)
    }
}
```

I want to import it into another module, like BookModule

```js
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { LoggingModule } from "src/logging/logging.module";
import { BookController } from "./book.controller";
import { BooksService } from "./books.service";


@Module({
    controllers: [BookController],
    providers: [BooksService],
    imports: [LoggingModule]
})
export class BooksModule {

}
```

and inside my controller I can do:

```js
@Controller('books')
export class BookController {

    constructor(private booksService: BooksService, private loggingService: LoggingService) {}
```

the question is:
When I need to import the whole module instead of the single service (LogginService) in providers, like:

```js
@Module({
    controllers: [BookController],
    providers: [BooksService,LoggingService],
})
export class BooksModule {
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

99% of the time, import the module. In Nest, if you import the module, you get the same instance of the already created class. If you add the `provider` to the `providers` array, you end up getting a new instance, which is not something many people usually want. So long as the module exports the provider, you'll re-use the created instance, which means less memory usage, and less leaks of the number of class instances, which means less time tracking down why `this.someClass.field` doesn't equal `this.someClass.field`

Comment: Is it documented in nest docs? I also had question if I import the same module in different places other places, will I get exported providers instantiated once or multiply times.

Comment: He is right about the instantiation. I tested it by adding a `console.log` in the service constructor using both approaches. I got 2 logs if when adding the service as provider and only 1 when importing the whole module.

Comment: This is a great answer. For smaller helper classes or simple one-off services, would you still recommend wrapping them with a module? Say you have a utility class, like `UrlBuilder`. Building a module around this (and possibly other such helpers) seems like it would lead to "module bloat", whereas injecting via `provider` seems viable. Maybe this is the 1% you're talking about?

Comment: @lux nothing says you have to have one module per provider. You could create a `UtilitiesModule` that holds the `UrlBuilder` provider (and others) and exports them. That is, if you want to ensure you only get one instance. If you aren't worried about memory or state then you could add a new provider each time

Comment: It's funny you say that about the `UtilitiesModule`, that thought just ran across my mind as well while looking at the IDE. It not only serves to reduce the memory footprint and ensure singletons, but also helps with code organization. Thanks very much for the input.